# Struct erro leitura do segundo nome

Tags: c, struct

Boa tarde,estou fazendo uma struct que armazena nome e idade,o primeiro passo do  laço,ele funciona normal,mas quando vai para ler o segundo nome ele pula,vai logo para a idade.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct teste{
char nome[30];
int idade;
};

int main()
{

    struct teste teste2[2];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("Digite Seu nome:");
    fgets(teste2[i].nome,30,stdin);
    printf("Digite sua idade:");
    scanf("%d",&teste2[i].idade);
    }
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("Nome:%s",teste2[i].nome);
    printf("Idade:%d\n",teste2[i].idade);
    }





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Limpe o buffer de entrada antes da leitura do próximo nome. Ele está pegando o '\n' que ficou no buffer de entrada e considerando o nome com zero caracteres. Veja o tem 12.18a de http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/.

Comment: Obrigado,deu certo agora